# Скатерть-самобранка

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология понятия "скатерть-самобранка"? Точнее, конкретно "самобранка". От "самому брать" или "браниться"?
(Собственно, вопрос возник, когда попыталась перевести это слово на английский язык)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. В общем-то скорее от *брать*. Но можно и от *браниться*. Но не в привычном нам значении.
Тут дело в том, что слова брать и бранить(ся) - родственны на уровне праславянской общности. Брань - церковнославянский вариант, вытеснивший русское *боронь* (отсюда борона). И это *боронь, бороться* восходит к тому же праславянскому (или даже индоевропейскому) корню -brat-, откуда развилось и современое *брать*.
Но только надо иметь в виду, что в *самобранке* подразумевается не тот, кто *берёт со скатерти*, а сама скатерть, которая сама *откуда-то берёт яства*. Правда *берет* не в современном значении *достаёт*, а в древнейшем - *несёт, приносит*, каким и было то самое праславянское -brat-. **Самобранка - сама приносящая**.

Да, точный перевод невозможен. Думаю, что лучше предлагаемого всеми словарями magic table-cloth ничего не найдётся. Или вообще без перевода оставить. Я как-то искал, как англичане называют волшебную мельницу Сампо из Калевалы - и ничего кроме magic mill не нашел. А ведь эта штука гораздо ближе к древнегерманскому фольклору. Куда уж тут русской скатёрке с не до конца понятными функциями.